# Call individually the output on foreach() to query in the database (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

**My Controller**

> 

```
        public function notification()
        {
            $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
            $data['results'] =  $this->lawmodel->notificationModel($id);
            $data['content'] ='contact_form';
            $this->load->view('includes/template2',$data);
        }
```

**My Model**

> ```
>        function notificationModel($id){
>             $this->db->select('*');
>             $this->db->where('requestedID',$id);
>             $query = $this->db->get('request');
>             return $query->result();
> ```

```
}
```

> **My View**

```
<h1>Sample!</h1>

<?php 
foreach($results as $row) 
echo $row->challengerID;

?>
```

>

The output on this code is

**SAMPLE!
38 42**

My problem is that since there is two output 38 and 42 , how can i get that output individually so that i can use each to query in the database

Example
(This is just a sample)
38 is one of the output on the above code..

> ```
>        function notifyIDUser( 38 ){
>     $this->db->where('user_id', 38 );
>     $query = $this->db->get("user");
>     return $query->result();
> ```

```
Im just new in codeigniter and i need to finish my project after new year..:(
```

Sorry my english is not good enough..

Comment: $results in the view is just $data['results'] in your controller, so loop $data['results']..

Comment: i put foreach on my controller but it will only display the last output of the loop..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process "notifyIDUser" in your controller like this

```
public function notification()
    {
        $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
        $data['results'] =  $this->lawmodel->notificationModel($id);
        foreach($data['results'] as $row) {
             $this->model_name->notifyIDUser($row->challengerID);
         }
        $data['content'] ='contact_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template2',$data);
    }
```

Comment: how can i call from my controller to my view? 
can i still use foreach() inside my view to call the column from the database? 

But thanks..
It gave me some knowledge..:)

Comment: if you want to use this to your view file then you must create "notifyIDUse" function in your helper file. create helper ex: user_helper.php under application/helpers directory and add following code `if(!function_exists('notifyIDUser')) {
    function notifyIDUser($id){     
        $ci =& get_instance();   
        $ci->db->where('user_id', $id );
        $query = $ci->db->get("user");
        return $query->result();
    }
}`

Comment: thanks!! i already get it ,but one problem is it only display the last ouput of the loop..:(

Comment: Use like this `foreach($results as $row){
 $someResult = notifyIDUser($row->challengerID); }`

Comment: it still display the last output..:(

Comment: Before you must check `$data['results']->num_rows()` and then you share your view file and helper code ? and object of `$data['results']`

Comment: Try this code `$someResult = array();foreach($results as $row) {
array_push($someResult,notifyIDUser($row->challengerID)); }`

Comment: sorry to ask this again..
how to call this to my view..it give me blank page..xD

Comment: thanks..I already solve the problem.

it will return blank because it is a multi dimensional array..
echo $someResult[0][0]->user_id

what i echo earlier is $someResult[0]->user_id;
i also use for loop to output all the data..^_^

thanks again..:)